# jquery - get html string of table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML that is being generated by some server-side code. The HTML that's generated looks like this:

```
<table id="myChoices">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" /></td>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Mar 7</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" /></td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Mar 8</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="3" /></td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Mar 9</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="4" /></td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Mar 10</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="5" /></td>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>Mar 11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When a user makes a choice, I need to get the two cells next to it. For example, if someone chooses the third option, I'm trying to get the following:

`<td>Wednesday</td><td>Mar 9</td>`

In my attempt to do this, I have the following jQuery:

```
function getHtml() {
  var html = '';

  var item = $("#myChoices input[type='radio']:checked");
  if (item.length > 0) {
    var grandparent = item.parent().parent();
    var cells = grandparent.children();

    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        var cellHtml = cells[i];
        html += cellHtml;
      }
    }
  }

  return html;
}
```

Unfortunately, my approach is not working. When I do the following:

```
var test = getHtml();
console.log(test);
```

I see the following in the console window:

```
[object HTMLTableCellElement][object HTMLTableCellElement]
```

Why? How do I get the actual HTML string?

Comment: with respect, please ensure that the question is correct when you post it. We all spent time creating responses that answered the original question and then when you changed the nature of the question to get the html rather than the text, it negated the .text() approach that several of us worked on. Irrespective of whether each post was correct or good, the question change negated them, meaning that the time we spent on our question was wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `outerHTML`, instead you are storing the jQuery object in the variable.

```
var cellHtml = cells[i];
```

should be

```
var cellHtml = cells[i].outerHTML;
```

**JS**

```
function getHtml() {

  var item = $("#myChoices input[type='radio']:checked");
  if (item.length > 0) {
    var grandparent = item.closest('tr'),
          cells = grandparent.children();

    var html = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < cells.length; i++) {
        html += cells[i].outerHTML + ' ';
    }
  }

  return html;
}
```

**[js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2mxs35p/2/)**

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, that approach does not include the actual "<td>..</td>". It only includes the text within the cells.

Comment: @user70192 Right. It includes the actual text. DO you also want to see the HTML ?

Comment: Yes. That is my fault. I did not encode my question correctly. I just updated it. I'm trying to see `<td>Wednesday</td><td>Mar 9</td>`

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n50s69u1/2/)

**Use this instead**

```
var cellHtml = cells[i].outerHTML;
```

**Complete JS**

```
  var html = '';

  var item = $("#myChoices input[type='radio']:checked");
  if (item.length > 0) {
    var grandparent = item.parent().parent();
    var cells = grandparent.children();

    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        var cellHtml = cells[i].outerHTML; //change here
        html += cellHtml;
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(html);
```

**Result format:**

`<td>Monday</td><td>Mar 7</td>`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, that approach does not include the actual "<td>..</td>". It only includes the text within the cells.

Comment: isn't that what you wanted? if you want with the html .. `var cellHtml = cells[i].outerHTML;` use this.. you'll get `<td>Monday</td><td>Mar 7</td>`

Answer (score 0):

I propose you change the script a bit to simplify the process altogether.

```
$("#myChoices input").change( function() {
     var string = $(this).parent().nextAll("td").text();
});
```

Variable "string" will contain the text you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery's siblings method:

```
 var textContents = $("#myChoices input[type='radio']:checked").siblings().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just use something simple like:

`$("input[type='radio']:checked").parents("tr").first().text();`

Example: http://codepen.io/cchambers/pen/ONNawo

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the `.html()` method on a dynamic `tr` which contains the other two `td` elements.

A trick is to clone them then wrap them in a `tr` and get the html of that

```
var others = $(this).closest('td').siblings().clone();
alert( others.wrapAll('<tr>').parent().html());
```

---

```js
$(function(){
    $('#myChoices [name="choice"]').on('change', function(){
       var others = $(this).closest('td').siblings().clone();
      alert( others.wrapAll('<tr>').parent().html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myChoices">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" /></td>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Mar 7</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" /></td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Mar 8</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="3" /></td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Mar 9</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="4" /></td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Mar 10</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="5" /></td>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>Mar 11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

In a function form it would be

```
function getHtml() {
  var item = $("#myChoices input[type='radio']:checked");
  var otherTD = item.closest('td').siblings().clone();

  return otherTD.wrapAll('<tr>').parent().html();
}
```